# Homebrew refuses to work on macOS Sierra

Tags: homebrew, macos, ruby

Just yesterday I updated my machine, a MacBook Pro (Mid 2010), to macOS Sierra. Everything seems to work fine, except when I try to use the homebrew packet manager with any command, for example `brew help`, the following error message is printed:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

I have not messed with anything related to ruby. Upon research I noticed that there seem to be some compatibility issues with Sierra and homebrew around, however, none seemed to match my problem exactly.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling homebrew? I seem to recall having issues with it every time I update macOS.

Comment: I found the underlying issue as well as the answer and will post a link to a discussion shortly.

Comment: Or so I thought. Unfortunately the solution proposed on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/4o37no/psa_fixing_homebrew_on_sierra/) does not work for me. I get the same error even after running chmod and running this let's me cringe anyway.

Comment: Have you tried the following: brew doctor

Comment: I get the same error for every brew command, including this one. Seemingly, Sierra has reset the rights for /usr/local. Earlier versions of homebrew, however, need those rights. What I can't explain to myself is, why running `chmod` does not do the trick for me.

Comment: Probably system protection. I found this command in my history – maybe give it a try? brew uninstall --force brew-cask; brew untap phinze/cask; brew untap caskroom/cask; brew update; brew cleanup; brew cask cleanup

Comment: Is it weird that /usr/local/Homebrew does not exist? Actually, on first sight I do not see anything related to homebrew except for the .git folder and the respective .gitignore. I am not able to create files/folders in /usr/local when running, for example,  `mkdir abc` without sudo. By the way, how should file ownership in /usr/local look like? Is ist correct that I am supposed to be the owner for every file and folder and not root?

Comment: So, I guess it is weird that there is no homebrew folder in /usr/local after all. At least there is nothing besides the .git folder and the .gitignore file. If it would have to do with permissions, as suggested in the Reddit link I posted, shouldn't I be able to run `brew` commands with `sudo` in front of it?

Comment: Actually, I was just sick of it now, so I took the easy road and uninstalled homebrew using the provided script on GitHub. After re-installing, everything works fine. I am not sure whether I should put this as an answer because it does not address the core of the issue, although it somehow solves the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the big picture: I solved the issue by uninstalling homebrew and then re-installing it again. In order to help people maybe gain a bit more insight, let me go into further detail.

Researching the Internet for the error message, my first hunch was that it had something to do with permissions. Check a discussion on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/4o37no/psa_fixing_homebrew_on_sierra/) or on the [Homebrew GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/49879#issuecomment-196294820) for reference. However, running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` did not to the trick. In any way, I would advise to be very careful using this command as it will transfer the ownership of `/usr/local` from the root user to yourself, which, apparently, was not intended by Apple. You can undo this by running

```
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local
```

However, note that this will only undo it for the folder `/usr/local` and not recursively for all its files.

So, I was left with uninstalling. If you want to do the same, type

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

in order to run the official script or see the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md) for reference.
Be aware that this will also uninstall all your Formulae and that you will be left with installing them manually again later on.

To re-install homebrew, simply run

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

If anyone figures out why I got the error in the first place or how it can  be addressed directly, please let me know.

Comment: I got the same error when I tried to update my homebrew with Ansible after upgrading to Sierra. Till I found your post, I was thinking that the Ansible module caused the problem, now it seems to be related to homebrew itself. Did you run `brew update` after installing Sierra?

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a small point in case it happens for anyone else - when running the uninstall script, the folders under `/usr/local/` were not being deleted after the uninstall of brew. This then caused issue with the fresh installation. So I had to manually delete those folders before running the install script, and it all worked then!